# If statement with any? in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

My view file to show list of `micropost` with answers is like this.

```
<li class="micro-dist">
  <%= render 'shared/micropost_content', micropost: micropost %>

  <section class="answer-<%= micropost.id %>">
    <%= render 'shared/answer_form', micropost: micropost %>
  </section>

  <% if micropost.answers.any? %>
    <% answers = micropost.answers.take(5) %>
    <div class="load-more-<%= micropost.id %>" >
    <ol class="answers" >
      <%= render answers  %>
    </ol>
    <%= link_to "Load more", more_micropost_path(micropost), remote: true, class: "btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block btn-mine" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

It should only show load more link only when `micropost` has answers. But its always showing load more link even when there is no answers. I found a better way to write the above code where if statement comes below answers variable defined.

```
 <% answers = micropost.answers.take(5) %>
 <% if answers.any? %>
```

It works. But I don't understand why the first one didn't work. In console its returning false but not in view? Can someone explain this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to check answers presence in `micropost` for example by printing `micropost.answers.count` before `if` statement.